# HERE Routing Parameter v7 vs v8

Tags: routes, here-api

With HERE v7.2 isoline routing it is possible to change the resolution of the routing (default was changed recently). In the migration guide to HERE Isoline Routing API v8 this parameter is marked as removed and currently not offered. Since my default for v7.2 is resolution=30 I want the same settings for v8. Is there a possibility to get the same results in v8 with different settings or is the implementation of this parameter already planned?

Answer (score 0):

Isoline Routing V8 does not support the parameter to change the resolution of the routing and the implementation is not planned in near future.